# Router Switch in React

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm trying to setup a basic Router in my React app. I just have the Main.js file that always opens and inside the Main.js file I have a href that navigates to the User.js

In my App.js, I try to set the router up

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import Main from './components/Main';
import User from './components/User';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/user" component={User} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then, in the Main.js I have something like:

```
<a href="/user">
```

When I run the application, the browser shows the error:

```
TypeError: props.history is undefined
modules/Router.js:20

this.state = {
   location: props.history.location
};
```

No error in the React terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be using `BrowserRouter`

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
```

or you could rename to fit your current syntax

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
```

you should also be using the `Link` tag to navigate within the router just to be safe.

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and use as

```
<Link to={`/user`} >
```

Answer (score 1):

After changes to React Router starting with 4.0.0, you should use BrowserRouter from the react-router-dom package when you are using browserHistory.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/user" render={props => <User {...props}/>}/>
      <Route path="/" render={props => <Main {...props}/>}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

or

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/user" component={User}/>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}/>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the import statement as below:

import { Route, Switch, **BrowserRouter as** Router } from 'react-router-dom';